# SystemError: <class 'pyodbc.Error'> returned a result with an error set

Tags: python, sql-server, pyodbc

```
def insert(self):
    conn = pyodbc.connect(
        'Driver={SQL Server};'
        'Server=DESKTOP-S0VG212\SQLEXPRESS;'
        'Database=MovieGuide;'
        'Trusted_Connection=yes;'
    )
    cursor = conn.cursor()
```

Error occurs when executing the query but I don't know what's causing it.

```
cursor.execute('insert into Movies(MovieName,Genre,Rating,Username) values(?,?,?,?);',
               (self.moviename, self.moviegenre, self.ratebox, self.username))
conn.commit()
```

Comment: Can you provide all of error massage?

Comment: File "C:/Users/Dell/PycharmProjects/untitled/gui.py", line 47, in insert
    cursor.execute('INSERT INTO Movies(MovieName,Genre,Rating,Username) VALUES(?,?,?,?);',
SystemError: <class 'pyodbc.Error'> returned a result with an error set

Comment: Thanks. I think (?,?,?,?); is strange and part of (self. .... ) should be inside '. So, cursor.execute('insert ......  username) ; ' ) will work.

Comment: @shimo I can't just write variable names in query right ? , that will save the variable names in the database instead of the values stored in variables

Comment: You are right, sorry. But I'm not sure ; is needed.

Comment: even after I remove ';' I get same error

Comment: It would be helpful if you could get the contents of the actual error message from `SystemError: <class 'pyodbc.Error'> returned a result with an error set`.  The code looks okay on the surface.  Perhaps the user does not have necessary permissions, perhaps one of the variables has the wrong type, perhaps one of the variables is null but the table column is not nullable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I know my answer is late, but it can be useful to someone.

`SystemError: <class 'pyodbc.Error'> returned a result with an error set` error appears when **the query is wrong**, make sure you are executing the correct query using SQL server query window then you can able to identify the problem.

In the question, the semicolon should not come to the end of the query, if you still get an error, it might chances for the column to have some constraint issue. So follow the below method when you are facing this issue.

> Execute one insert query in the SQL server query tab and identify the
> problem.

Comment: I get this error even when the query is perfectly valid, but the table already exists when I execute a `'CREATE TABLE'` query without dropping the existing table. This exception did not include an `ORA-00955` like I expected, and it later causes a `UnicodeDecodeError`, which threw me off for a couple hours while debugging.

Answer (score 0):

Using SQL Server with an Openquery to an Oracle Server I got this error because I had a comment in my Oracle SQL.

```
SET NOCOUNT ON;
If(OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Temp_OracelTable') Is Not Null)
Begin
    Drop Table #Temp_OracleTable
    End


SELECT *
    INTO #Temp_OracleTable
    FROM    OPENQUERY (OracelConnectionNameOnSQLServer, '
Select Column -- Comment I had to remove
From TableName')
Select * From #Temp_OracleTable
Drop table #Temp_OracleTable
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're having this problem with Apache Airflow, you should look for 2 possibles causes:

- If you're calling your function inside the file, Airflow doesn't deal with it.
- If your query string is correct with you default encoding.